# Let users choose between Google Maps and Apple Maps in IOS 6?

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit, ios6, ios6-maps

I am using basic MapKit functionality in my iOS app.

Is there a way to let my iOS 6 users choose between Google and Apple maps for the mapping data presented within my app? If so, how can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You can let users choose between iOS maps and other maps (OpenStreetMap, Microsoft VirtualEarth, CloudMade, OpenAerialMap, OpenCycleMap, SpatialCloud, TileStream7) with route me (on github) or you can go with Bing maps (also a library available).

But you'll have to code for the different libraries as the MapKit Framework is only available for Apple maps in iOS 6.

Answer (score 3):

[ClassicMap](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/ClassicMap) (GitHub) does exactly what you're looking for. The sample project shows how to add a Google Maps overlay to MapKit and how to switch between Google and Apple maps.

It works well, but zoom levels seem to be limited to Apple's data (I'm pretty sure that the maximum zoom was higher in Google Maps, at least where I live).