# MKMapVIew shows googleMap in iOS 5 and Apple map in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, mkmapview, ios6-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Let users choose between Google Maps and Apple Maps in IOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524012/let-users-choose-between-google-maps-and-apple-maps-in-ios-6)

In my app, i have used MKMapView which shows google maps in iOS 5.0 but it shows Apple map in iOS 6.0. I, want to show google map in both the OS, because Apple Map is not available in iOS 5.0. Is it possible?  Any suggestion will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

[Let users choose between Google Maps and Apple Maps in IOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524012/let-users-choose-between-google-maps-and-apple-maps-in-ios-6)

That question pretty much answers it, however someone else on here has provided a Google maps overlay you can try!

https://github.com/mladjan/GoogleMapsOverlayiOS

Comment: @Craig- i have tried that code from gitHub but, it also shows iOS map irrespective with the description of that project.

Comment: Ah thats a shame, it was only an overlay anyway really. Looks like there is no way to do it (That has been discovered yet) :P

Comment: you haven't tried that project?

Comment: Nope, as i said, someone else provided it and i said you can try it :)